Which states contribute to the largest gap for WZW model with $so(16)_1$?
I was told that the WZW model with $so(16)_1$ occurred at $(c,\bar c )=(8,8)$, and it had a gap, i.e. the smallest state with conformal dimension $\Delta = h+\bar h\neq 0$, and it was said to be $2$.
What was the holomorphic and anti holomorphic weight of this state?
